# Matplotlib Show Yticks with no value for x

Tags: python, matplotlib

Im kinda new to Python, and really really new to matplotlib.

Let's say i have this `x` and `y`:

```
x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y=[9, 9, 8, 8, 7]
```

In general, my y values are between 1 and 9. And i want to plot those values, even if i don't really have them on my Dataset, so i tried this :

```
plt.yticks(ticks=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
plt.plot(x, y)
```

But it's not really working.. it's only plotting y= 9, 8 and 7. How can i plot 1, 2 , 3, 4, 5 and 6 ?

Full code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y=[9, 9, 8, 8, 7]

plt.yticks(ticks=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
plt.plot(x, y)
```

Comment: what do you mean by " How can i plot 1, 2 , 3, 4, 5 and 6 ?"

Comment: @abhilb like i said, in general my y values are `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` but in this example, `y in between 7 and 9`. I want to plot the missing values, even tho if their correspondant x is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this to force matplotlib to set the axes limit.

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_ylim([1,9])
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to change the order

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y=[9, 9, 8, 8, 7]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.yticks([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
plt.show()
```